# Why ist it calling the destructor of Gameboard gameboard in line if (players[p].setcoin(gameboard, input))

Tags: c++, destructor

In main i have the following code:

```
Gameboard gameboard(8, 5);
HumanPlayer hp1('A'), hp2('B');
HumanPlayer players[2];
players[0] = hp1;
players[1] = hp2;
gameboard.show();
//int p = player
int input, p = 0;
while (cin >> input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
    case 1:
        if (players[p].setcoin(gameboard, input))
        .
        .
        .
```

In class HumanPlayer i call the function of gameboard and return it

```
bool HumanPlayer::setcoin(Gameboard g, int row)
{
    return g.setstone(name, row);
}
```

In class Gameboard i set the coin (if it is full i return false)

```
bool Gameboard::setstone(char player, int row) 
{
    for (int y = height; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        //row-1 da das array bei 0 beginnt
        if (elements[y][row-1] == '.')
        {
            elements[y][row-1] = player;
            return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function passes the Gameboard by making a copy:

```
bool HumanPlayer::setcoin(Gameboard g, int row)
{
    return g.setstone(name, row);
}
```

This means everything you do with g inside the function will not have effects to the original that you passed into it. At the end of the function the copy of g gets destroyed.

If you don't want to do this use:

```
bool HumanPlayer::setcoin(Gameboard& g, int row)
{
    return g.setstone(name, row);
}
```

The ampersand means that you want to pass a reference, which will not cause a copy to be made.

Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be useful to you.